# In what ways can Daleks be killed?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

Daleks are incredibly powerful, but not invulnerable. My question is, **based on what we know (audio and spin-off stories will work too), what does it take to kill or incapacitate one of these exterminating menaces**? Are there particular weapons that work well on them? Could a well-armed human take one out? Is it possible to trick them into trouble?

Comment: Well armed in terms of 21st century weaponry, or the most advanced we've seen on the show, or anywhere in between?

Comment: Dalek history covers decades of story production, and millennia of in-universe time. Over this span, their capabilities have shifted dramatically. Can you narrow your question to a particular era?

Comment: This is very broad indeed. We've seen dozens, if not hundreds of ways to kill daleks in the shows. Big laser guns always seem to work quite well, as do massive explosions, dropping stuff on them and covering them in volcanic magma.

Comment: Prior to [Genesis](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Genesis_of_the_Daleks_(TV_story)), you could simply [cover up the eye stalk, push it onto a tarp so it loses power and then pry open the shell and take out the creature inside](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Daleks_(TV_story)). Nowadays you usually need really powerful weapons, but [sometimes just pushing it out the window will work](https://media.giphy.com/media/YmgHnArbvweis/giphy.gif). It varies a lot.

Comment: It is my understanding that Doctor Who is not very big on that kind of continuity.

Comment: Like the Borg, the Daleks are almost infinitely adaptable. Partly because they have the tech from all the many species they've destroyed and partly they're just that determined to be the last species standing.

Comment: Man, I really wanted to see someone pushing a Dalek out the window, but @Ixrec's gif is 404. Guess someone pushed _it_ out the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, Daleks are incredibly hard to kill.

From what we saw in the new Doctor Who series(2005), Daleks cannot be taken out by humans with regular weaponry.

The only instances we've seen Daleks die are:

1. Rose Tyler disintegrating them.
2. River Song killing one in Big Bang 2.0
3. Self-destruct.
4. Dark-star alloy(although that only gets the Dalek to open up it's armour)
5. The Time War.

Safe to say, they're fairly indestructible unless you're a Time Lord.

Comment: They were a bit less impressive in Old Who (before the 2005 reboot). See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtUMnn0-4zw), where Ace disables one with what looks like just a big stick.

Comment: @randal'thor - hahaha.. I also remember how stairs were a Dalek's worst enemy!

Comment: It can be a bit inconsistent: If you look at "Death to the Daleks", it was left to some Stonehenge tribe to hit them with sticks! However, perhaps this could be attributed more to self destruct (as seen later on in this story, and that was used to good effect in "Dalek")? But it is difficult to explain this away in "Dalek Invasion of Earth" when a van mows them down, or "Rememberance of the Daleks" when one is thrown from a few floors of a building.

Comment: @Randal'Thor that stick had been altered by a powerful Time Lord artefact.

Comment: Don't forget they can also be taken out by game show host robots (The Parting of the Ways).

Comment: This is very interesting; I am less familiar with New Who.  In the classic series, they were more or less indestructible against *bullets* (see UNIT's first encounter with the Daleks) or small bombs (see "The Dalek Invasion of Earth").  But....in the very first Dalek episode  (second Dr. Who episode, "The Daleks"), all it took was a cloak, some mud, and some ingenuity....

Answer (score 1):

In a 2005 episode the Doctor says that if the humans focus their fire around the eyepiece of a dalek then they should be able to incapacitate it:

> The Dalek's surrounded by a force field. The bullets are melting before they even hit home, but it's not indestructible. If you concentrate your fire, you might get through. Aim for the dome, the head, the eyepiece. That's the weak spot.
>
> <sub>-- Series 1 Episode 6, *Dalek*</sub>

And we see this done in a later episode. However during the battle of Canary Wharf, at least fifty soldiers and at least twenty Cybermen all focus their fire on the Daleks, and some of the humans are wielding weapons that the Doctor modified and we see disabling Daleks earlier; however in that scene not a single Dalek even seems mildly interested in enemy weapons.

Comment: Could you expand on this?

Comment: @Jonah better now?

Comment: Does disabling it by breaking the eyepiece equate to killing it?